# How to send news using Discord chatbot using API in Python?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, discord, chatbot

I am making a discord chatbot using python where my bot sends news by using API but I am unable to do it.

**My code:-**

```
import requests
def get_news():                           #========================================News
  url = "https://google-news1.p.rapidapi.com/top-headlines"
  load_dotenv()
  querystring = {"country":"INDIA","lang":"en","limit":"50","media":"true"}

  headers = {
      'x-rapidapi-key': "os.getenv('NEWS_API')",
      'x-rapidapi-host': "google-news1.p.rapidapi.com"
      }

  response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
  json_data=json.loads(response.text)
  return json_data

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('|news'):    #====================================News
      data=get_news()
      list1=message.content.split(" ")
      try:
        num=int(list1[1])
      except:
        num=5
        i = 1
        for item in data['article']:
           if not(item['description']):
              continue
           await message.channel.send(str(i)+". "+item['url'])
           if i == num:
               break
           i += 1
```

I am using API from https://rapidapi.com/ubillarnet/api/google-news1/

But I face some error

**My error:-**

```
$ python -u "d:\Code\python projects\Discord_Chat_BOT\main.py"
We have logged in as Buddy#9784
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\soham\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\Code\python projects\Discord_Chat_BOT\main.py", line 218, in on_message
    for item in data['article']:
KeyError: 'article'
```

**Please help me to fix this error**

Comment: Can you please add `print(json_data)` right before `return json_data` in `get_news()` and rerun so that we can confirm it's value?

Comment: When I print this it gives me `{'message': 'You are not subscribed to this API.'}` . But I had subscribed it in rapidapi.com

Comment: Your apikey syntax to get `NEWS_API` from os env in `headers` may be incorrect. My suggestion is to do 1 of 2 things. 1) Explicitly type out your `x-rapidapi-key` in `headers` or 2) create a variable like `news_api = os.getenv('NEWS_API')` and then `x-rapidapi-key: news_api,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is this:

```py
headers = {
      'x-rapidapi-key': "os.getenv('NEWS_API')",
      'x-rapidapi-host': "google-news1.p.rapidapi.com"
      }
```

You are literally sending the text `"os.getenv('NEWS_API')"` as the key, instead of running `os.getenv('NEWS_API')` and sending the value as the key. Since the string `"os.getenv('NEWS_API')"` is not a valid key, you don't have permission.

Instead, remove the quotation marks to send the actual key:

```py
headers = {
      'x-rapidapi-key': os.getenv('NEWS_API'),
      'x-rapidapi-host': "google-news1.p.rapidapi.com"
      }
```